# regex_token_iterator issue in Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 RC

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I installed the Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 Release Candidate and now seem to have a problem with a use of `sregex_token_iterator` that so far seemed to work fine. To verify I tried the following sample code from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator) (note that I changed the variable `text` to have a white space at the end):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string text = "Quick brown fox ";
    // tokenization (non-matched fragments)
    // Note that regex is matched only two times: when the third value is obtained
    // the iterator is a suffix iterator.
    std::regex ws_re("\\s+"); // whitespace
    std::copy(std::sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), ws_re, -1),
              std::sregex_token_iterator(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Running this gives the following assertion:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140D.dll
File: c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xstring
Line: 247

Expression: string iterators incompatible

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
```

Is that a bug in the Visual Studio STL implementation or is the example for `regex_token_iterator` wrong?

Comment: cppreference.com examples are strict with the standard and the error happens in the C runtime instead of throwing an exception, so i'm sure it's a bug in the STL implementation. At least the MSVC devs were so smart to add an assert for this expected case.

Comment: I'd recommend to use boost regex, STL regex implementations often are buggy (for me at least) and switching to boost just requires to change the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that -- as part of performance fixes we did in `<regex>` for Update 2, we don't make a ton of temporary string objects any longer; if a `sub_match` instance doesn't match something, we just make value-initialized iterators which behave "as if" there is an empty string match.

This program should be valid as of C++14 (and is morally what's happening inside `regex_token_iterator`); see "[null forward iterators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3644.pdf)":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main() {
    // Value constructed iterators conceptually point to an empty container
    std::string::iterator beginIt{};
    std::string::iterator endIt{};
    printf("This should be zero: %zu\n", endIt - beginIt);
}
```

... but our debug asserts prohibited this. `regex_token_iterator` just happens to trip over it.

Note that in release builds (with debug asserts turned off) this will all work fine; the bug is in the iterator debugging machinery, not in the iterators' behavior.

This bug will be fixed in 2015 Update 2 RTM.